# Calling a method from another class in Java doesn't work?

Tags: java, class, methods, compiler-errors

So I have two java files (with one public class in each) inside the same package saved in the same folder. The folder hierarchy reflects the package name. Now, inside one of the classes, I would like to call a method from the other class. As far as I am concerned, this can be done by calling: `someClass.someMethod();`.
When I do this, the file does not comply. It yields an error message saying that it couldn't find the method.* I have checked for typos but there are none. I have also tried to help the program by importing the class with `import somePackage.someClass`, but without any result. The only way I can make it work is by either removing the package from both files or by copying the method to the other file, none of which is desirable in the long-term.

Do you have any idea what could cause the error and how it can be solved?
Many Thanks!

- The error looks like this:

  `TestBit.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        boolean value = someClass.someMethod(arg1, arg2);
                        ^
    symbol:   variable someClass
    location: class otherClass
  1 error"`

EDIT: 
Here is the code:

```
package uk.ac.prejava.ex1; 
public class PackedLong{
        public static boolean get(long packed, int position) {
            long check = (packed>>>position)& 1;
            return (check == 1);
        }
    }
```

and

```
package uk.ac.prejava.ex1;
public class TestBit {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  long currentValue = Long.decode(args[0]);
  int position = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
  boolean value =PackedLong.get(currentValue, position);
  System.out.println(value);
```

}
    }

I would like to call PackedLong.get in the second class, but when complying javac can't find the file.

Comment: how have you defined your someclass's someMethod?

Comment: Please add your code, it's difficult to find  the solution without it.

Comment: You have to have an instance of `someClass` first.

Comment: And follow java naming conventions. packages go all lowercase; but classes start UpperCase. Not adhering to those simple rules makes your code very much confusing.

Comment: @MichałSzewczyk I have added my code now!

Comment: @GhostCat Thank you for the reminder, I believe my real code follows the conventions.

Comment: Not sure what you believe; but somePackage violates conventions; and so does someClass.

Comment: Ok, but where is static set() method in PackedLong?

Comment: @GhostCat That was only a psuedo code visualising my issue. As you can obviously see, the real code I have included does not violate the rules.

Comment: @MichałSzewczyk Oh, there was a little typo. Now the correct code with PackedLong.get is included! Thanks for the notice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you have the following package structure:

- somePackage

  - someClass
  - otherClass

Here is what might be wrong. While comipling your code you should be in the directory just above somePackage. So when you see directory listing you should see only somePackage. Now you will have to compile the class using the following:

```
  javac somePackage/otherClass.java
```

Hope that works.

Comment: This is something I have not been able to do! I don't know why, but I only seem able to comply the code if I am inside the package directory or else I get the "file not found" error. However, I can only run the code from the directory just above the package, as described by you. Do you have any idea what might cause that problem?

Comment: You need to be in folder directly above `somePackage` and type `javac somePackage/otherClass.java` with `/` not `.`

Comment: @Whatzs Oh I see! Now it works complying! However, when I run a class file i still use `.`, don't I?

Comment: @Whatzs Wow! Following your advice I could comply both files from the driectory above without issue!

Comment: Corrected the post accordingly. Thanks

Comment: @Anshuman Thank you very much for your help!